# Problema con las notificaciones webhooks de mercadopago

Tags: php, html, mercadopago, curl, webhook

Tengo una pagina la cual se dedica a vender objetos digitales (no tangibles), los cuales quiero enviar al correo electrónico especificado por el usuario una vez tenga la comprobación del pago y sepa que ese pago ya esta realizado correctamente. Para realizar el pago tengo implementado el SDK del checkout pro de mercado pago. Para comprobar el status del pago tengo entendido que se realiza mediante las [Webhooks](https://www.mercadopago.com.ar/developers/es/guides/notifications/webhooks), indicando una `notification_url` en la cual por método POST se te envía una notificación en formato json con la información del pago que se acaba de realizar. Luego, con el id brindado, mediante una `curl request` se obtienen los datos especificos de ese pago, como el status y demas... Ahora lo que necesito saber es como vincular cada notificacion que recibo a la venta correspondiente, para luego comprobar el status de ese pago, y que a su vez, si el status es `approved` se le envie automaticamente el correo (que ya tengo diseñado) a su comprador. Adjunto código que estoy tratando.

Declaro la preferencia:

```
$preference = new MercadoPago\Preference();
$preference->notification_url = "https://hookb.in/Oee00NG6POsqOdYYO3r8";
```

Obtengo los datos enviados en formato json:

```
<?php
//Url donde esta nuestro JSON
$req = 'https://api.mercadopago.com/v1/payments/1239281369?access_token=TEST-7098767024588341-062501-c7b383a1432f579d5a8f899845f9eca4-780970445';

//Iniciamos cURL junto con la URL
$cVimeo = curl_init($req);

//Agregamos opciones necesarias para leer
curl_setopt($cVimeo,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

// Capturamos la URL
$gVimeo = curl_exec($cVimeo);

//Descodificamos para leer
$getVimeo = json_decode($gVimeo,true);

//Asociamos los campos del JSON a variables
$status = $getVimeo['status'];
$status_detail = $getVimeo['status_detail'];
?>
```

Agrego para ponerlos en contexto: En resumen, lo que necesito hacer, es que mi pagina quede automatizada, un usuario compra un producto, se comprueba el status del pago, una vez el pago sea correcto, se le envía el producto al usuario y se guarda en mi base de datos como una venta realizada.

Comment: ya preguntaste en soporte de mercado pago???

Answer (score 0):

Lo que puedes hacer es pasar como external reference el id de la compra que hayas hecho en tu tienda (esto al momento de crear la preference), de tal manera de que al recibir el id del pago, puedas buscarlo con más detalle en mercado pago, obtener dicha external reference y actualizar el estatus de tu pedido en tu base de datos.

Comment: Esto parece relamente un comentario mas que una respuesta. Con un poco mas de reputación, [vas a poder comentar en cualquier lado.](//es.stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment). Por favor mira [answer]